# Loading a CSS on loadURL before DOM

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to know how can I load a `css` on a website before it loads.
I have tried the code below in `main.js`

```
win.webContents.on('did-start-loading', function () {

        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/home.css', "utf-8", function (error, data) {
            if (!error) {
                var formatedData = data.replace(/\s{2,10}/g, ' ').trim()
                    win.webContents.insertCSS(formatedData)
            }
        })
    })
```

It did work but the original style of the website popped up for few seconds and then it loaded my style, which makes zero sense if the original CSS and mine got whole different style.

I also tried loading the CSS below in `preload.js`

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", injecting)
function injecting() {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'https://example.com/hello.css';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(link);
}
```

It also did not work. It keeps showing the original style and then loads my css after a second.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the speed of the CSS download, but you can achieve a similar behavior. You could have `body` as:

```
<body class="invisible">
    <!-- Some HTML here -->
</body>
```

and some helpful CSS

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, you could do

`document.body.className = "";` once the CSS is loaded as:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", injecting)
function injecting() {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'https://example.com/hello.css';
    link.onload = (() => {document.body.className = "";});
    document.documentElement.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: But the thing is... I'm doing loadURL and I don't have control over the website or the HTML

Comment: @jeputier I understand. In that case you can add document.body.display = "none" as the first operation you have and document.body.display = "block"; when the link has loaded.

Comment: I did what you said and it did not work... Could you update your question with the right way?

Comment: @jeputier it did not work how? Did you get some errors in the console? You could also create a JSFiddle with your problem (this is mostly a Javascript problem anyway). If you do so, then we would have an easier time detecting and fixing the exact issue.

Comment: I don't really know what's "JSFiddle" also, it did not give any errors. It worked but it still shows the original website for a second and then switches to mine. Plus the body tag in the html doesn't even have any class...

Comment: Hello? You here

Comment: @jeputier okay, so, to answer you about JSFiddle, it is an online available tool by which you can freely create reproducible examples of your problems: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @jeputier as about the issue you have: it seems to be the case that the script I have provided was executed too late, that is, the page has already been loaded at the point when body is hidden. But I'm just speculating. Please create a JSFiddle and share the link here, so that I will be able to play around your problem.

Comment: i don't know what am i supposed to send you as jsfiddle cause nothing basically works, i'm using your code and it just does not work...

Comment: @jeputier You need to create a minimal reproducible example of the problem. Without that I can only wish you good luck in solving your problem.